# How to Edit and Remove item from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

This code to store items in sessionStorage so i want to add, edit ,
remove item and remove all my code worked well except remove item i
don't know the reason

```
function clearItem () {
            for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
                var a = sessionStorage.key(i);
                var b = sessionStorage.removeItem(a);
            }
        }
```

[here's my code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mferry/4uqkp7hu/)

Comment: why you are assigning the remove method to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clearItem () {
            for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
                var a = sessionStorage.key(i);
                sessionStorage.removeItem(a);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

1. You have indicated that you only want to remove the phone number from sessionStorage here. In this case, there is no need to loop over sessionStorage at all. Just remove that one entry:

   ```
   sessionStorage.removeItem("number");
   ```
2. In looking over the Fiddle that you provided, your code was quite disorganized and didn't make much logical sense from a "flow" perspective. I have modified it to a working version available **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpdurjo3/38/)**.  **The biggest issues with your code was that you are trying to loop over sessionStorage when saving and retrieving the values, when what you should have been doing is simply creating key/value pairs of data and accessing the data with the key names you've created.**

Read about [`sessionStorage` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: I don't wanna to clear all items in the same time I already have the function to remove all I want to remove one by one also

Comment: @MohamedFared Please explain "one by one". What should this function do? How many items should it remove? Which one(s)?

Comment: it's form to save phone numbers in session storage

Comment: But, please answer the specific questions I've asked: *What should this function do? How many items should it remove? Which one(s)?*

Comment: I have tow functions first to remove all 2nd for remove single item

Comment: I'm trying to help, but you're not answering my questions. What exactly would you like **this** function to do?

Comment: I answered @Scott i want this function to remove single item

Comment: @MohamedFared You have not answered. WHICH item? What is the criteria for knowing WHICH item should be removed?

Comment: please take a look here  jsfiddle.net/mferry/4uqkp7hu that's my code the item is number phone

Comment: it's not working .. after I trying to add more numbers each number is deleted before